# How to convert and slice jpg to psd and keep layers

Tags: software-recommendation

**[COPIED TO GRAPHIC & DESIGN](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28485/how-to-convert-and-slice-jpg-to-psd-and-keep-layers)**

I have several JPG designs of a website I'm developing. I did a pure HTML website and then did a full webpage screenshot for the design part. Now the client is asking for the PSD files, is there any way I can convert the JPG designs to PSD in GIMP or any other software?

**EDIT**
Is there any way I can slice up the JPG into the individual layers?

---

For confidentiality reasons, I can't upload the actual designs but here is a [sample](https://creativemarket.com/premiumcoding/8553-Elegantica-Website-PSD-Template) from [creative market](https://creativemarket.com/):

[image]

Comment: I am flagging this question as too broad considering the latest edit. You add a totally different question that is not even related to Ubuntu. I suggest you remove the second question and post it at [Photo.StackExchange](http://photo.stackexchange.com). Note that [JPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpg) is simply an image compression algorithm.

Comment: This is bizarre. If you did not use photoshop, the client should not ask for the psd file. Just explain that the psd file is just worthless in this case.

Comment: I think this is a valid question, but maybe you should rephrase it: Is it possible to edit HTML files in GIMP using layers? Not sure about this.

Comment: Don, changing a question to something different after it already has two answers is not within the rules of the site.

Comment: You can't get the layers from a jpg file for the simple reason that they don't _exist_. JPEG does not support layers and the image is flattened when you export to JPG. This goes double if you're talking about a screenshot, where would the layers come from?

Answer (score 1):

Install imagemagick:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then

```
convert image.jpg image.psd
```

Visit [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) for more info.

Comment: Is there anyway to separate the different layers?

Comment: I think you can export psd layers to different jpg but I'm not sure that a single jpg can keep all the layering information.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a JPG image to PSD format in GIMP 2.6 (Ubuntu 12.04) do the following:

1. Open the JPG file with right click and then choosing ***Open With*** > ***GIMP Image editor***.
2. In GIMP open the export dialogue by following ***File*** > ***Save As...***.
3. In the *Save As...* dialogue change the file name extension to ***.psd***.
4. In the *All images* drop down list select ***Photoshop image (*.psd)*** (see the image below).
5. Click ***Save***.

[image]

In GIMP 2.8 (Ubuntu 13.10) there is a special *Export* dialogue that you can access through ***File*** > ***Export...*** but that works in similar way.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't slice up the layers. See my edit.

Comment: I answered to you original question. If you have another question please post it separately.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple:

**No** you can split in layer a jpeg file reliably you will have to do it on your own.

`jpeg` is like a painting, the only way you could transform it into 3D would be to generate the part behind each element when you remove an element from the painting.